# Unpacking RGB values of a point cloud from PCD file

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I saved a point cloud of type `PointCloud<PointXYZRGB>` in ASCII PCD file.  Below is a part of this file -

```
# .PCD v0.7 - Point Cloud Data file format
VERSION 0.7
FIELDS x y z rgb
SIZE 4 4 4 4
TYPE F F F F
COUNT 1 1 1 1
WIDTH 38603
HEIGHT 1
VIEWPOINT 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
POINTS 38603
DATA ascii
1.4766392 -0.82155049 -0.0032610297 1.7976693e-38
1.4766392 -0.81364399 -0.0032610297 1.7884862e-38
1.4766392 -0.80577451 -0.0032610297 1.78845e-38
1.476639 -0.79794157 -0.0032609701 1.7607545e-38
1.476639 -0.79014462 -0.0032609701 1.7883416e-38
1.476639 -0.78238314 -0.0032609701 1.7791942e-38
1.476639 -0.77465671 -0.0032609701 1.769975e-38
1.476639 -0.76696479 -0.0032609701 1.6409733e-38
1.476639 -0.75930673 -0.0032609701 1.6593762e-38
```

[As per the documentation](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.0/structpcl_1_1_point_x_y_z_r_g_b.html) of `PointCloud<PointXYZRGB>`, the color values can be unpacked based on the formulation given below-

```
// unpack rgb into r/g/b
uint32_t rgb = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(&p.rgb);
uint8_t r = (rgb >> 16) & 0x0000ff;
uint8_t g = (rgb >> 8)  & 0x0000ff;
uint8_t b = (rgb)       & 0x0000ff;
```

I manually tried to unpack the color values of in a separate code and found all colors values as black. Below is the code snippet-

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    uint32_t rgb = 2.2949836e-38;
    uint8_t r = (rgb >> 16) & 0x0000ff;
    uint8_t g = (rgb >> 8)  & 0x0000ff;
    uint8_t b = (rgb)       & 0x0000ff;

    printf("rgb=%d, r=%d, g=%d, b=%d", rgb, r, g, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Below is the output-

```
rgb=0, r=0, g=0, b=0
```

**My goal is to unpack the RGB colors defined in PCL.** Please note that I am using PCL 1.7.1.

Comment: `uint32_t rgb = 2.2949836e-38;` this isn't an **integer**. Where did the `reinterpret_cast` go?

Comment: probably do something like `float x = 2.2949836e-38; uint32_t rgb = *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&x);` .. looks quite sloppy (and assumes certain representations), but matches the documentation you're citing.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: It works `rgb=16377550, r=249, g=230, b=206 ` however, I am confused about `reinterpret_cast` statement. Can you please explain it by providing the answer?

Comment: I don't know this library, but for some reason, they decided to take an RGB (ARGB?) value and use it as a representation of a `float`, assuming IEE-754. That's just strange. The `reinterpret_cast` will reverse this and interpret the bytes of this `float` as if it was an `uint32_t`.